# Make django handle subdomain suffix

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

We're hosting several dockerized web-apps on our webserver, let's call it `group.example.com`. Our subdomains are handled via nginx as suffixes though, which translates to something like `group.example.com/app1/` `group.example.com/app2/` as root urls.

When using Django, we run into problems though, as all its urls generated by `url` in the templates such as `<a href="{% url 'index' %}">home</a>` will be relative links, so rendered to `<a href="/">home</a>`. This relative link will not be interpreted correctly, leading to the main, non-app page `group.example.com`.

So the goal is to have an app based prefix such as `/app1/` for all links. I can hardcode these for static links, but there has to be a more elegant way. Also this leads to problem for the used forms submitting to the wrong page - redirecting again back to the main, non-app page `group.example.com`.

I tried adding `/app1/` to all registered urls as prefix, but that doesn't seem to work either - that way the app is running but user would need to visit `group.example.com/app1/app1/` to get to the index, and the relative links still don't work correctly.

In the app docker-container we're running the web-app with `nginx` and `uwsgi`. It works fine when using correct subdomains such as `app1.example2.com` - but we don't have that capability on our new faster webserver we want to host the app on.

Is there a way to resolve this using the app containers `nginx`, `uwsgi` or `django` / middleware config to get the links to resolve to `group.example.com/app1/` as root?

Comment: Editing the container `nginx-site.conf` to `server_name group.example.com/app1/` didn't help either, links still don't resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is two ways to resolve it.

**One** use `SCRIPT_NAME` in the NGINX configuration. For example, based on this [server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/233506/233599):

```
location /app1/ {
    SCRIPT_NAME /app1;
    # rest of the config
}
```

**Two** You can add [**`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#force-script-name) in your settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app1'
```

FYI, I would prefer using first solution.

Comment: Couldn't get option one to work, but `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app1'` did the trick. In that case I also had to change the static files from  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app1/style.css' %}" /> ` to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app1/static/app1/style.css" />`